# ASP.NET RegEx: How do I replace all occurances of Eval(?????)

Tags: asp.net, regex, visual-studio

I have this which occurs hundreds of times in our project (with one space on both sides):

```
Eval("RandomDataName")
```

I wish to replace this with (with one space on both sides):

```
H(Eval("RandomDataName"))
```

Right now I have,

```
Eval\({.*}\)
```

And replace with:

```
H(Eval(\1))
```

This works, but not on lines in which there are multiple Eval, as it selects all of them on the same line. How can I fix this? I've tried using .*? and that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be more explicit, the current regex is too greedy.

For instance, say you have this on a line.

```
Eval("Test") Eval("Another") Eval("Yet one more")
```

Your regex will match `Eval(` and proceed to the very last `)`, capturing everything in between. The easiest way to get this to work would likely be to have a "whitelist" of characters you expect. Something like:

```
Eval\([a-zA-Z0-9\" ]*\)
```

This would match `Eval(`, then match quotes, alphanumeric characters, and spaces zero or more times and then finally match the closing `)` of each `Eval()` statement.

I would recommend tossing some sample `Eval()` statements into [RegExr](http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/) and testing out some regexes and see what works for your data set.

Comment: Thanks! This was immensely helpful.